# How to access to a CSS file in HTML?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I know this is basic and a straight forward question, however couldn't seem to get my html file read the css file and background-image doesnt work.

This is my CSS:

```
body, html {
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
width: 100%;}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" />
```

File Tree:

web/
   static/
         file.css/

web/ templates/
         file.html

web/ images/
         image.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS would load fine (assuming the URL to `file.html` is `/templates/file.html` and you aren't just using it as a server side template for a different URL) if you got the filename correct (it is `file.css` and not `style.css`).

The `width: 100%` should apply and create a (short) horizontal scrollbar, but there shouldn't be any other effect.

The image won't load because URLs are *relative to the stylesheet* and `/static/images/background.jpg` doesn't exist (according to your directory structure).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you elaborate on why image won't load. What kind of a directory structure do you think would work better?

Comment: @Pythoner1234 — With the CSS you have now, you would need to move the images directory inside the static directory.

Answer (score 2):

in the CSS file...

```
body, html {
background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
width: 100%;}
```

The `../` tells the path to back up out of the directory where the CSS file is located, and *then* look for the `images` directory.

Comment: I have tried it. But, for some reason still not reading the image.

Comment: @Pythoner1234 check your file names.... in the question you mention `style.css` and `file.css` which one is correct? Also be aware of cacheing in browsers. You may need to hold the `Shift` key down and *then* reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" />`

to : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/file.css" />`

You must give the correct path to the CSS file, in your tree you named the css file 'file.css' not 'style.css'

Answer (score 0):

Try your css file as here:

```
body, html {
background-image: url('/web/images/background.jpg');
width: 100%;}
```

Also use the css link tag in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/web/static/file.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check the exact names you used to name the files.

1. You have used file.css and image.css but in you HTML it is Style.css

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/style.css" />`
2. Try:

   `body, html {
   background-image: url('/web/images/background.jpg');
   width: 100%;}`